# Adding a temporary value to total value?

Tags: java

There seems to be a problem with this. I'm grabbing a value from another class and saving it into a `Double` called `tempMoney`. This is grabbed in a method form another class. Then I want to add the `tempMoney` to `totalMoney`. The idea is to keep adding the `tempMoney` value given to `totalMoney` which makes `totalMoney` going up and remember itself.

When it is run, it does the initial calculation. However, when the next time the method is called, it seems to forget `totalMoney` and it starts from 0.0 again, instead of starting from `tempMoney` from previous calculation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Accountant {

    Member m = new Member("",0,0,"");
    President p = new President();
    Double totalMoney = 0.0;

    public void pay(Double tempMoney) {

        System.out.println("Would you like to pay for your membership now? Y / N");
        Scanner sYes = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yesS = sYes.next();

        if(yesS.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            totalMoney = totalMoney + tempMoney;
            System.out.println("Total money " + totalMoney + " temp money " + tempMoney);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: Please post properly formatted code in your question, not a screenshot of code.

Comment: To answer your question: That most likely means that you have created a new `Accountant` object somewhere (in code that you didn't show), instead of re-using the object you created earlier that holds the previous value of `totalMoney`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
public static Double TotalMoney = 0.0
```

Instead of

```
Double TotalMoney = 0.0
```

Comment: That worked thanks. But can you explain why exactly it did?

Comment: You should try and research about static and dynamic variables. In Java, a variable without any static declaration will be reinitialized whenever you called an object. If you want to keep the variable alive, you have to add static keyword

Comment: Ask your professor more about object oriented programming concepts and java keywords or learn it online 
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-oops-concepts
http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/java-introduction/